# Error in Linkedin "This uploaded file has been marked private by the author. Sorry!"

Tags: linkedin-api

Any Idea why this error comes after uploading files through Media Section?
Getting the Above error while uploading Resume in Linkedin.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about LinkedIn

Answer (score 1):

I was involved in the same problem, don't care, you need to follow some steps:

1. Login on your profile at https://www.slideshare.net;
2. Upload a new presentation;
3. After that go to "My Upload" on your profile and click on "Add to my profile".

Good Luck for your job!
Regards

Comment: Thanks for the reply user7598856. I see now they have enabled the option.

Answer (score -2):

I have come against this same message as I was trying to add to my profile. The linkedin reply is unfortunately the same bs that they give for everything else they've taken away from us.

"Adding, Editing, Moving, or Removing Work Samples on Your Profile:

We recently improved the LinkedIn desktop experience. Adding, editing, moving, and removing work samples on your profile is temporarily unavailable. Thank you for your patience."

Comment: I have checked with few others and they are able to add the media file though.